# Android - show spinner while loading data from db

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to have a spinner (ProgressBar) show on screen while loading some search results from a database, as there is a second or two of lag before they display. I have a button 'view all' which returns all results from the db. It's essentially strucutred as follows:

`// onClickListener() { // set ProgressBar visibility to visible // call method to return all results - ProgressBar set to GONE at end of this method }`

The issue I'm having is that everything in the onclick is executing in one go, meaning there is still a pause while the results are loaded, but the spinner is set to visible and gone simultaneously and therefore never actually shows on the screen. Can't seem to find a way around it.

I've followed all the documentation I can find but haven't figured anything out.

Comment: Which document did you follow? Can you share your code to understand the issue?

Comment: @AmjadAlwareh I’m avoiding posting any code as it’s a uni project and don’t want anything flagging as a similarity. But basically it’s set in the xml, initialised in the Java code and set to ‘invisible’ in the on create method, and I’m then trying to turn it ‘visible’ in the on click listener one the view all button is clicked, and back to ‘gone’ at the end of the method that’s rendering all the data. Hope that helps but can provide some small chunks of code if not.

Comment: Most likely what you want is to retrieve the data in the background. The issue here is that the flow is: onClick gets called => onClick updates the UI and returns => the main thread processes and displays the UI update. If your function waits for data for a few seconds, the main thread will be clocked and the entire UI will freeze until you get your data. You should look into coroutines or having some onDataLoaded callback, that automatically gets called after the wait, if it's available.